# Adding a comma and a plus sign (+) to numbers on the x axis of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted the following figure, which shows numbers on the x axis. What I want is to add commas and plus signs on these numbers. What I would expect is "+100,000" or "+200,000". Nonetheless, I have only managed to do it separately, as: "100,000" or "+100000"
[image: Figure]

I used the following code.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = difference_gdp, y = difference_rate, color = region)) +  
  geom_point(size = 4) + 
  xlab("Variation in GDP per capita, 1990 vs 2019")  + 
  ylab("Variation in age-standardised\nT2DM-attributable deaths per\n100,000 people, 1990 vs 2019") +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", aes(x=difference_gdp, y = difference_rate, color = NA), digits = 2, p.accuracy = 0.05) +   
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = 'y~x', se = FALSE, aes(color = NA)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) sprintf("%+d", x)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(y) sprintf("%+d", y))
```

I know the code to add the comma is `scale_x_continuous(labels = comma)` but I don't know to add it to my previous code.

Comment: Please provide a reprex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the scales package covers this use cases

e.g

```
scales::number_format(prefix = "+",big.mark = ",")(1000)
```

maybe this works, can't test it

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = difference_gdp, y = difference_rate, color = region)) +  
geom_point(size = 4) + xlab("Variation in GDP per capita, 1990 vs 2019")  + ylab(
  "Variation in age-standardised\nT2DM-attributable deaths per\n100,000 people, 1990 vs 2019"
) + stat_cor(
  method = "pearson",
  aes(x = difference_gdp, y = difference_rate, color = NA),
  digits = 2,
  p.accuracy = 0.05
) +   geom_smooth(method = 'lm',
                  formula = 'y~x',
                  se = FALSE,
                  aes(color = NA)) +  scale_x_continuous(
                    labels = scales::number_format(prefix = "+",big.mark = ",")
                  ) + scale_y_continuous(
                    labels = scales::number_format(prefix = "+",big.mark = ",")
                  )
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for positive values, but as I also have negative values, they also had a plus sign on them (eg "+-1,000"). Nonetheless, as you said, the scales package was perfect for this. I explored a similar code, and it worked! scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(show_plus_sign = TRUE, big.mark = ","))

Comment: Nice can you please upvote and mark as the answer?

Comment: `number_format()` is deprecated in the scales package; you should switch to `label_number()`. Moreover, using "prefix" will also add plus sign to negative values in your Y axis. Updated and correct syntax will be `labels = label_number(style_positive = c("plus"))`.